# What files need to be overwritten to move an active WordPress site to a local version for development?

Tags: wordpress

I want to take the files from an active online WordPress instance and develop on my local machine. I will only be doing front end development so I don't need any database other than my local dev environments which is a MAMP stack. 
What folders and files do I need to pull from the online version to add to the local version?
An obvious example would be the 'Themes" folder , but what else? What is the full list? Is there a list of these items online?

Thank you.

Comment: I didn't know there was a wordpress stackexchange. I'll delete it, Oops too late. Feel free to migrate the question. I don't have the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look into wordpress plugin `Duplicator` meant for taking backups or transferring entire website from one location to another.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

The plugin page also contain short tutorial on what it is capable of..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get a theme on which you are going to work from the themes folder.

On your local machine have the same wordpress version installed as on live and install all the plugins that you have on live wordpress.

In this way you`ll only need the theme folder and nothing else for development.

Comment: Edit - Ignore my last comment

Comment: If you have images also, then you need a copy of `wp-content/uploads/`folder too on your local machine.

Comment: Ok. I wrote that comment assuming the image folder for the respective theme held that information thus I scratched my comment